# Fix to position in canvas without losing responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html

I have `nine` boxes  of **class box** with values in it, I have another **class box002** which have the number image displayed in it.

**box002** can be dragged and dropped to corresponding starting number in **box**, then that column get deleted.

I have done a background for this with a **name board** and **hanging board** and its responsive.

I want to `fix these nine boxes exactly inside the name board an the number image in box002 inside the hanging board. When the nameboard and hanging board size changes when i resize the window the elements should correctly fit inside the nameboard and hanging board.`

How can this be achieved?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>


  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Sigmar One';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Sigmar One Regular'), local('SigmarOne-Regular'), url(https: //fonts.gstatic.com/s/sigmarone/v8/co3DmWZ8kjZuErj9Ta3do6Tpow.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
    
    @import url(https: //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One);
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    h1 {
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 2;
      /* position: absolute;
  top: 0; */
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .heading {
      margin-left: 20%;
      margin-right: 20%;
      margin-top: -2%;
    }
    
    .hint {
      margin-top: 100%;
      margin-bottom: -10%;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
      height: 110px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #333;
      border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
      margin: -2px;
      border-radius: 10%;
      background-color: #99ffff;
    }
    
    .box002 {
      float: left;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-left: 74.3%;
      margin-top: -84%;
      margin-bottom: 70%;
      background-color: #ffff00 2px;
      border: px solid #000066;
    }
    
    #timer {
      font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
      margin-top: -20%;
      margin-left: 120%;
    }
    
    #heading {
      font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
      color: #F534BB;
    }
    
    #container {
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-align: center;
      border: px solid #CC0000;
    }
    
    .containerr {
      padding-top: 30%;
      padding-right: 30%;
      padding-left: 30%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      border: px solid #FF3399;
    }
    
    .pic {
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    
    .container2 {
      margin-top: 10%;
      margin-right: 50%;
      margin-left: -10%;
      border: px solid #009;
      border: px solid #FF3399;
    }
    
    p {
      font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .text {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 7 px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    body {
      background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/eV5WW9/background.jpg);
      background-size: 100vw 100vh;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js'></script>



</head>

<body onload="buildImage();">
  <script>
    window.onload
  </script>



  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>


  <script>
    var timeOut;

    function buildImage() {
      document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
    }

    function changeImage() {
      index++;
      if (index >= images.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
      document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + (index + 1) + ')';
    }

    var index = 0;
  </script>

  <script>
    var audio = new Audio("correct.mp3");
    var audio2 = new Audio("wrong .mp3");




    function playAudio() {
      audio.play();
    }

    function playAudio2() {
      audio2.play();
    }

    function pauseAudio() {
      audio.pause();
    }

    function cancelAudio() {
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
  </script>




  </h1>

  </div>
  </script>


  <h4 id="timer" style="color:#ffc34d; font-size:29px"> Time <span id="countdowntimer">0 </span></h4>

  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <div class="containerr">
      <div class="pic" id="content">
        <div id="container">

          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2container">

          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="3container">

          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
            <p name="values"></p>
          </div>
        </div>




      </div>


    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
    <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:120px; height:120px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
  </div>
  <div class="hint" style="color:#ffffb3; font-size:20px; font-weight:bolder;" align="center">
    <h4>Hint:uncover the hidden picture by dragging and droping the clock to its correct time</h4>
  </div>
  <script>
    var items = [{
        label: '1:40',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1'
      },
      {
        label: '2:20',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2'
      },
      {
        label: '3:50',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'
      },
      {
        label: '4:45',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4'
      },
      {
        label: '5:35',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5'
      },
      {
        label: '6:10',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6'
      },
      {
        label: '7:15',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7'
      },
      {
        label: '8:10',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8'
      },
      {
        label: '9:30',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
      },
      {
        label: '10:40',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10'
      },
      {
        label: '11:25',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=11'
      },
      {
        label: '12:50',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=12'
      }
    ];

    var tempimages = [];
    var array2 = [];
    array2 = items.slice();

    var backimgcount = 1;
    var len = array2.length;

    var item;

    var timeleft = 1;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
      timeleft++;
      document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
      if (timeleft >= 100)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    }, 1000);


    var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'];
    var index = 0;

    function buildImage() {
      document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
    }

    function changeImage() {
      index++;
      if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
      document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
    }






    function rvalue() {

      elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#1aff1a";
        //elements[i].borderRadius = "2px";
        elements[i].style.border = "2px solid #ffff80";
        //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"

      }

      ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');







      for (var index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length),

          item = array2[randomIndex];

        ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
        ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
        tempimages.push({
          data: item,
          index: randomIndex
        });

        ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
      }

      var tlen = tempimages.length;


    }


    function displayAllImages() {
      if (tempimages.length == 0) {
        rvalue();
        //return;

      }
      //tempimages = tempimages.concat(tempimages.splice(0,2));
      //item = tempimages.splice(0, 1);

      function shuffle(array) {
        var currentIndex = array.length,
          temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {

          // Pick a remaining element...
          randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
          currentIndex -= 1;

          // And swap it with the current element.
          temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
          array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
          array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
      }

      // Used like so
      var arr = tempimages;
      arr = shuffle(arr);



      item = arr.shift();
      image = document.getElementById('slide');
      image.src = item.data.url;
      image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;


    };

    $(function() {

      displayAllImages();

    });

    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {

      ev.preventDefault();


      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      var el = document.getElementById(data);
      //alert(data);
      //alert(el);

      var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
      var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;

      //alert("x=>" + x + " y=>" + y);

      if (x == y) {
        //el.parentNode.removeChild; 
        playAudio();

        ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
        ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';

        var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
        //ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
        pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

        item = this.item;
        var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;
        array2.splice(arrayvalue, 1);






        //alert("sucessfull");
        if (tempimages.length == 0) {

          rvalue();


          //changeImage();

          changeImage();
        }
        displayAllImages();

      } else {
        playAudio2();
        alert("WRONG TIME PLACED");
      }

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please narrow your code example with a **minimal** example.

Comment: I will try my best on your opinion as it is valueble for a starter like me

Comment: I appreciate your learning efforts. For the record (and for future questions) you should try to ask questions that are more general - so they become useful for future users having the same type of problem. In this particular example, only posting the relevant HTML and CSS (without js) would have helped. My answer should serve as an example of how to clean up unnecessary code when asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all boils down to this:

```css
.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.container2 {
  width: 35vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 41.5vh;
  left: 14vw;
}
.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}
```

... and some cleanup.

---

But there are a large number of things not right in your example. I'm genuinely impressed it runs (and I never said this to anyone before, on SO). Initially I agreed with Kaiido's suggestion (you should only present enough to reproduce the issue, not the entire page) but, the more I looked into it, the more I realized it would be an impossible task, considering the state of your code.

With all due respect and the most helpful intentions, you should consider going through a few basic lessons on HTML. At the very least, your code should validate. Use an HTML validator, which will help you fix a good number of errors. At the very least, whenever you open a paired tag you should close it. Another very serious problem is you can't have more than 1 `<head>` tags.

Here's a trimmed down version of your layout, doing what you want:

```css
.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/eV5WW9/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.container2 {
  width: 35vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 41.5vh;
  left: 14vw;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28vh;
  left: 72vw;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 16vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="0">1:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="7">8:10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="4">5:35</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="2container">

        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="11">12:50</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="9">10:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="11">12:50</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="3container">

        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="0">1:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="3">4:45</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="2">3:50</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" id="2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" data-item-index="2">
</div>
```

Comment: is  there a way i can fix the number displayed in class box002 to the hanging board exacly without losing responsiveness

Comment: I've added it to the example. Open it and inspect to get it currently applying CSS. You want to use `vh` and `vw` which are equal to 1% of viewport height and 1% of viewport width. Alternatively, if you want to place them inside a parent with `position:relative;` you could use `%` units, apply `top:0; left:0` to them and use `transform: translate(tx,ty) scale(sx,sy)` to place them at the desired location.